# Disable item in ListView

Tags: angular2-nativescript

I have an application written in NativeScript with Angular 2. In it I have a list view like this:

```
     <ListView row="1" [items]="items" (itemTap)="onNavigationItemTap($event)" class="root-drawer-content">
         <ng-template let-item="item">
             <StackLayout class="root-item-stack-layout">
                 <Label [text]="item.title" textWrap="true" class="btn btn-primary" [class.btn-active]="item.enabled"></Label>
                 <StackLayout height="1" class="root-drawer-content"></StackLayout>
             </StackLayout>
         </ng-template>
     </ListView>
```

How can I force specific item to be disabled? Both visually and in terms of behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. As you are using item.enabled property to choose the btn-active class, you can apply the same logic to for disabled(Your custom one e.g change the background color to gray to look disabled) to StackLayout.

```
<ng-template let-item="item">
             <StackLayout class="root-item-stack-layout" [class.enabled]="item.enabled">
                 <Label [text]="item.title" textWrap="true" class="btn btn-primary" [class.btn-active]="item.enabled"></Label>
                 <StackLayout height="1" class="root-drawer-content"></StackLayout>
             </StackLayout>
         </ng-template>
```

And for the functionality, you can handle that in your .ts file where your manage the itemTap.
(itemTap)="onNavigationItemTap($event)"

```
public onNavigationItemTap(args) {

        const currentItemView = args.view;
        const item = currentItemView.bindingContext;
if(item.enabled){
// do your stuff
}
```